# Crystal Reports date from DB

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a problem to display a date in crystal reports. The field is from database, and it shows the time, too. I need to display only the date.
I observed that if I click on the Text Format from the date, in the Font tab at Sample it is showed with time. I think that is the problem, but I can't modify, I can't delete the time from the Sample box.

Do you have any idea how to resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The data-type of the column inside the database seems to be `text`/`varchar` instead of `datetime`.

The best would be to fix the data-type on the table inside the database.
If you don't have the option to change the datatype directly on the database, you can use following formula to convert it to `DateTime` inside the report.

```
If IsDate({Table.DateTimeColumn}) Then DateTime({Table.DateTimeColumn})
```

On the properties of the formula field there will be the option for the different formats then.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I managed to change, by clicking on the formula Format Editor, and there I selected the correct format